# FreeRadius: EAP-PEAP proxy to PAP Radius Server?

Tags: okta, freeradius, radius

I am using Okta as central ID Provider with a radius agent for SSL VPN. I would like to integrate 802.1x for WiFi authentication as well.

Okta does not support 802.1x/EAP and I am trying to build a proxy that is proxying EAP-PEAP MsCHAPv2 requests to the okta radius agent which only supports PAP. Is this possible? I found a configuration to Proxy EAP-TTLS with PAP, but this is not supported by macOS/iPhone without central MDM/signed profiles.

Looking forward to your Ideas!
Thanks
Tobias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved 802.1x auth via Okta with EAP-TTLS and PAP. Documentation: https://help.okta.com/en/prod/Content/Topics/integrations/cisco-meraki-radius-intg.htm